# Does the Fuji X100F have an actual "rear curtain" flash sync.?

Tags: flash, fujifilm, fujifilm-x100, second-curtain

By "rear curtain" I mean firing the flash towards the end of an otherwise normally metered and timed exposure - including in manual mode, in contrast to "slow sync" which at least on the X100 is timed automatically.

Preemptive - the fact that the X100 series doesn't have shutter curtains due to using a leaf shutter is completely irrelevant, "rear curtain" is just a name that stuck from the original design, with an electronic camera it should be possible to trigger the flash at an arbitrary point during the exposure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Using the Flash](http://fujifilm-dsc.com/en/manual/x100f/shooting/flash/index.html) in the [FujiFilm X100F Manual](http://fujifilm-dsc.com/en/manual/x100f/):

> **Sync**
>
> Choose whether the flash is timed to fire immediately after the shutter opens (**1ST CURTAIN**) or immediately before it closes (**2ND CURTAIN**). **1ST CURTAIN** is recommended in most circumstances.